# Javamail: Send a HTML mail with an "unclickable" URL on it

Tags: html, email, jakarta-mail

I come with an issue that is giving me some headaches.

I'm sendind some e-mail confirmations, using JavaMail and an HTML template, that is written on the message content.

This HTML template, has a URL on it, but this URL is not wrapped into a  tag, it's just a plain text inside the HTML body.

The problem is that the URL appears as a clickable link on the mail message, and that's not the behavior I'd like. I'd prefer the user to copy and paste the URL to the browser (security policies at work)

Have any of you done something like this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do this.

The key is to insert a ***zero width space*** `(&#8203;)` somewhere between the URL

So, I changed my URL from

```
http://my.site.com/somecontext?contextid=somekeyvalue
```

to

```
ht&#8203;tp://my.site.com/somecontext?contextid=somekeyvalue
```

And now the URL is not interpreted as a link by the mail clients, but it's still good for a copy-paste to the browser.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You cannot control how mail user-agents handle incoming mail. Mail clients do this for the convenience of the user. I fail to see how this is a security issue.

The only alternative is to put the URI in an attached image, but that would just annoy your users.

Comment: +1 since I share the same observation about mail clients. I work on a Bank, so almost anything is a security concern, so I have nothing else to do but to *fix* it...

Comment: @CristianMeneses For that kind of email, I wouldn't put a hyperlink or even a text address in there. I would instruct the user to manually visit the bank's official website and follow instructions or directions on-screen. Remind them that this is so they know they're on the real bank website and not a fake link in a phishing email.

Comment: Already done that, but it is a business requirement to deliver a mail with a URL pointing to a specific site, but without the link being clickable on the email :(

Comment: @CristianMeneses Then the business requirements are simply bad. Contact the person who wrote them to inform them that they need to be redone.

Answer (score 1):

you could explicitly code the url to not be a clickable link (a without the href)... It will still appear as a link, but it won't be clickable.

EDIT: It seems the user below is correct.

EDIT2: It actually seems I may have been correct.  I tried composing an email at 
http://putsmail.com/tests/838716156f824732c7f5456122c38e

with the html:

```
<html>
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
<a>http://www.google.com</a>
</html>
```

and the second link appeared as text.

You can't explicitly insert html in the gmail client, but you can with your own.

EDIT:

I went back this morning and tried this html:

```
<html>
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
<a>http://www.google.com</a>
http://www.google.com
</html>
```

and only the second link was plaintext. Just FYI...

Comment: +1 for your testing.. I'll try this in the morning, thank you!

Comment: This didn't worked after trying it, and sending it to some mail clients.

Comment: How are you sending/composing the email?

Comment: If the mail is truly being interpreted as HTML, it should work.  The below poster may be correct in that you can't control how people's mail clients handle incoming email, but if a client truly interprets HTML as HTML, then the above is correct.  I verified that this is true with GMail.  Did you try cc-ing a gmail account when you sent out the emails?

Comment: Yes. I'm using a HTML template, which is loadad on the JavaMail message content. Looks like no mmater the technique, the mail clients try to translate URL to links. Some techniques work on Gmail, but not on Outlook or Apple Mail (as the case above). Then I found out about the "zero width space", which worked on all of them. That's why I stated "after trying and sending it to some mail clients".. Just because, when it works, it doesn't cover all the possible cases, as it only would work with Gmail